# Software & Updates wheel privileges

Tags: permissions, 22.04, sudo, groups

I need to use Software & Updates to enable some sources.

My system says "On some systems, you need to be in a special group (often: wheel) to use this program."

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G wheel xxx
[sudo] password for xxx: 
usermod: group 'wheel' does not exist
```

I search the web for advice on adding users to the group 'wheel' and I get only articles about adding users to sudoers.

So I feel a bit stuck. How to proceed?

Comment: When does your system say "My system says "On some systems, you need to be in a special group (often: wheel) to use this program."? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: `wheel` is a superuser group used on FreeBSD systems, so it's not applicable on Linux. Which Ubuntu version are you using, and which application gives you this `wheel` message?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Studio 22.04, based on KDE Plasma desktop. It's /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk ("Software & Updates"). It asks for my password for su permissions, then complains about "wheel."

Comment: Oh but now, mysteriously, it has actually accepted my password. Days, I'd type my password and it would be rejected, now it's fine. Weird. OK, close this one.